# How to generate full report in owasp zap in any format

Tags: owasp, zap

When i try to generate report in HTML,.XML or PDF I'm getting only alerts in the report. I would like to get all the information including passed attack also in the report.

For example in active scan there is around 500+ combination of URL being used but I'm getting only fee of them. I need all the 500+ URL and its results in the report

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We dont generate that as a 'standard' report as no ones asked for that to date. However we do expose pretty much everything via the ZAP API, and if theres anything we dont currently expose then let us know and we'll fix that.
To get started with the API point your browser at the host:port that ZAP is listening on and follow the link to the API UI which will allow you to invoke any of the end points. We also have some info on the wiki: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiDetails

If you have more detailed questions then the ZAP User Group is a good place to ask: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: i've tried with ZAP API with ruby, still i'm not able to get the full report. posted the same query in google groups as well

Comment: And answered on the User Group :) https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/hLaWSQC3YHY/ZKabl0YTBAAJ

Comment: Our customers would like to know what was tested. I imagine such a report could be a checklist with passed, high, medium and low marks. Now if you generate a document and everything is fine you effectively get a blank page.